# mixing date formats in the same document

Tags: datetime2

I am trying to make dates in my CV uniform so I thought of using the `datetime2` package. The problem is that sometime I have a full date, sometimes the year and the month, and sometimes only the month. I couldn't find a way to do this with the commands provided by the package. What I would like to accomplish is something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\selectlanguage{USenglish}

\begin{document}    
\DTMdate{2019-1-15}
\DTMdate{2019-1} % <- error here
2019 % I don't need special command here

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to extend the package to accomplish this?
Or is there perhaps a better package to do this properly? I also need data ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your own function that could handle supplying only a year, or a year-and-month, or a full date (year, month and day). Below I use [`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse) to break an input of the form `<year>-<month>-<day>` into 3 separate components. A missing component receive `-NoValue-` which can be used in a test `\IfValueTF{.}{<true>}{<false>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\selectlanguage{USenglish}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\setdate}{> { \SplitArgument { 2 } { - } } m}{%
  \@setdate#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\@setdate}{ m m m }{%
  \IfValueTF{#2}
    {\IfValueTF{#3}
      {\DTMdate{#1-#2-#3}}% Year, month and day
      {\DTMdate{#1-#2-1}}% Year and month only
    }%
    {\DTMdate{#1-1-1}}% Year only
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setdate{2019-1-15}

\setdate{2019-1}

\setdate{2019}

\end{document}
```

You can update the components above (commented) and replace it with a new function if you want to print/process the year-only, or year-and-month only outputs. For example, using

```
% ...
\usepackage[useregional,calc]{datetime2}
% ...

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\setdate}{> { \SplitArgument { 2 } { - } } m}{%
  \@setdate#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\@setdate}{ m m m }{%
  \IfValueTF{#2}
    {\IfValueTF{#3}
      {\DTMdate{#1-#2-#3}}% Year, month and day
      {\DTMmonthname{#2} \number#1}% Year and month only
    }%
    {#1}% Year only
}
\makeatother
```

(note the addition of the `calc` component for [`datetime2`](//ctan.org/pkg/datetime2)), you get

[image]

Comment: If you provide only year and month it should say January 2015 only. Am I missing something?

Comment: @aaragon: Yes. I mention you can define your own displays for the separate conditions. I've added something to that effect at the end of my answer.

Comment: Very nice! Last question. Is there any option that we can pass so that months are abbreviated? So print `Jan.` instead `January`.

Comment: And would it be possible to easily insert a range of days? Something like `\setdate{2010-05-{20-24}}` to yield `May 20-24, 2010` (this doesn't work).

Comment: @aaragon: Perhaps ask a [follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764) to address that. As an aside: How would you propose a date range that spans multiple days *and* months (or years)?